# Where does the url come from?

Tags: java, android, string, url, google-play

I have recently released my app, but the url is not my package name. Before releasing my app, I had changed my package name from `com.example.ruchir.buttonsmasher` to `com.curlybrace.ruchir.balloonpopper`. The thing is, in my url for the play store, the url still says the first package name, without the example part:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.culybrace.ruchir.buttonsmasher

So, my question is. Where does the play store get the package name from to use in the url? That way, I can change it and update it. This brings me to my second question, is it okay to update it with a different package name? Then the url's will be changed, right?

I have done this:

```
Edit->Find->Find in path… dialog
```

And searched up `buttonsmasher`, and have found 10 occurences. So, **is it okay to change the package name? Will it mess things up? I am planning on making an update, so can I change the name for the update? Will the url change?**

Thanks so much for your help,

Ruchir

Comment: The package name uniquely identifies your app, so if you change it, then it will be considered a new app.

Comment: @ChrisStillwell It does not. It says `buttonsmasher` while it should be `balloonsmasher`

Comment: @Buddy The thing is, the package name is **already** `com.curlybrace.ruchir.balloonpopper.` I just want the url to reflect that, which it isn't

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Ah, I was honing in on the `com.culybrace` and `com.example` parts. I see where you are coming from now. Just to prevent future confusion you may want to highlight that in your question.

Comment: @ChrisStillwell Sorry for any confusions. It is weird because the manifest **does** declare the package to be the correct one. But, as stated earlier, the url is a different package name. Do you think I should go to each occurrence where I see `buttonsmasher` and change it? WIll it have to be a new app then? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only place that matters is the AndroidManifest.xml.
You set the package name in the package attribute in the manifest element.

```
<manifest package="com.curlybrace.ruchir.balloonpopper" ...
```

It may and usually does correspond to your java package names.

You might also check your build files. In case of gradle, the applicationId overwrites your manifest attributes.

Comment: Yes, and the package I have in the manifest **is** correct. But, for some reason, the **url** is not

Comment: And that is my package attribute in my manifest. But, as you can see in the link I have provided, the url is different

Comment: Do an experiment: Download your app from playstore, unpack the apk using apktool and open your AndroidManifest.xml and check the package attribute. What do you find?

Comment: what is apktool? Also, why do I need to do that, since it is clear that the package I put in my app's manifest is correct? Does play store look for a different place to put their url's package? In that case, can I change it?

Comment: You don't need to do that, but it might reveal to you what the playstore received from your upload. Would you mind checking  the package name in developer console? What do you see there?

Comment: I figured out what happened. It is in the build.gradle. It has the wrong package name. What do I do now? Can I change it? Does the url even matter that much?

Comment: Should I just leave it as is, and not worry about it? What benefits will I get by fixing the package name by publishing a new app?

Comment: I think customers will not pay much attention to the url. Since your app is published already, I'd leave it as it is. Lessons learned.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help. I have marked you best answer

Answer (score 2):

> is it okay to change the package name? Will it mess things up? I am
>   planning on making an update, so can I change the name for the update?
>   Will the url change?

No it's not okay AT ALL to change the package name. An app's package name is the UNIQUE identifier in the play store. You change one character in it...you have a totally new app.
If your app's package name change, obviously the URL will change too.

To properly set a unique package name which should NEVER change for the same app:

1. If, for some reason you're still using Eclipse, in your manifest file:

   ```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="COM.YOUR.PACKAGE">

       <application>
           <!-- the rest of the specs -->
       </application>
   </manifest>
   ```
2. If(and hopefully) you use Android Studio and Gradle, this is how yor gradle file should look like:

   ```
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "COM.YOUR.PACKAGE"
           minSdkVersion 15
           targetSdkVersion 23
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0.0"
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Where "COM.YOUR.PACKAGE" should be you're app's package name.

Comment: Oh my gosh. I just realized that my Build.gradle file has the wrong package name! What do I do!? I need to change it to balloonpopper, I can not have it be buttonsmasher!

Comment: So that means, my app has two different package names! At the top of every activity it says the right one, but in the build.gradle, it says the wrong one!

Comment: Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What do you suggest I do now? Does it really make much of a difference on what the url is? Because my app name on the play store is Ballon Popper, and there is nothing about `ButtonSmasher` except in the url. You can see that: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.culybrace.ruchir.buttonsmasher

Comment: When I was first making the app, I just randomly chose the package name ButtonSmasher, and I guess I didn't change it properly

Comment: If you have a really large number of users on your old app, I'd say the easiest but not the most elegant way to do this, is to release an update with your old app, where you pop up a message (with a button redirecting the user to your new app's play store page), asking the user to download your new app.

Comment: Does the url even matter that much though? I don't have many users, but that seems like a hassle to do...What would you do?

Comment: Would it help my app be higher up if someone typed in balloon

Comment: The url does matter because it points to 2 different apps. If you do not have so many users, I wouldn't worry about it too much. If you still worry about those users, I would release an update with what I mentioned and remove the app from the store...

Comment: So I should just publish another of the same apps with a different url?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95967/discussion-between-mike-and-ruchir-baronia).

Comment: Hey, I am making an app, and I need to change the package name. How can I do that? I have looked at a ton of pages, but don't know what to do...Thanks!